# gnu gcc source archives signed with expired GPG key?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, key, gcc

I'm in the course of rescuing a legacy app that got left behind and turned out to be needed on rare occasions, one of which occurred yesterday. I need to rebuild some libraries and the libraries have a strict dependance on gcc > 6.0 which the server sadly lacked by a mile. So I went looking for a newer gcc and found mirror sites here:https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html such as http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-9.3.0/. (Aside: so many sites still answer over http, not https, oh yay!)

The gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz archive signature in gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz.sig is with the key for Jakub Jelinek listed on the gnu.org page, fingerprint `33C2 35A3 4C46 AA3F FB29 3709 A328 C3A2 C3C4 5C06`.

This key is in the ancient keyring at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg, and has expired.

Why are recent versions of gcc, of all things, being distributed this way? Is there some refreshed version of this key I'm not finding? Or a different mirror site using a different signing key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pedantic answer to your question is: when gcc-9.3.0 was released, the key was not *yet* expired:

```
$ gpg --verify gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz.sig gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Thu 12 Mar 2020 07:32:47 AM EDT
gpg:                using DSA key A328C3A2C3C45C06
```

The signature was made in March 2020, but the key expired in September 2020:

```
gpg --list-keys A328C3A2C3C45C06
pub   dsa1024/A328C3A2C3C45C06 2004-04-21 [SC] [expired: 2020-09-10]
      33C235A34C46AA3FFB293709A328C3A2C3C45C06
```

So, the fact that it's expired *now* is not a cause for concern.

What *is* the cause for concern is that it's a 1024/DSA key, which is probably not considered sufficiently strong these days. However, I can also see that the author has a newer key created in May, 2020:

```
pub   rsa4096/6C35B99309B5FA62 2020-05-28 [SC]
      D3A93CAD751C2AF4F8C7AD516C35B99309B5FA62
```

So, perhaps the next release of gcc will be signed with this key instead.